# Change name of properties saved into Cosmos Db without using JsonProperty attribute

Tags: c#, json, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I need to change the name of the properties saved into Cosmos Db. I don't want to use the JsonProperty attribute from Newtonsoft.Json because using it has the effect to always change the property's names, also in JSON response when I call an action method. So I would that only the JSON saved into Cosmos Db has different property names. To do this, I've created a custom attribute named CosmosDbPropertyAttribute as following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CosmosDbPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public CosmosDbPropertyAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

The following is a sample class that uses the CosmosDbProperty attribute:

```
public abstract class CosmosDbDocumentBase : ICosmosDbDocument
{
    [CosmosDbProperty("CID")]
    public virtual string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [CosmosDbProperty("DT")]
    public virtual int DocumentType { get; set; }

    [CosmosDbProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [CosmosDbProperty("PK")]
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
}
```

During serialization all works fine because I've overridden the CreateProperty method in my custom ContractResolver in the JsonSerializerSettings of the DocumentClient object.

```
public class CosmosDbDefaultContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty jsonProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CosmosDbPropertyAttribute)).FirstOrDefault() is CosmosDbPropertyAttribute PropertyAttribute)
        {
            jsonProperty.PropertyName = PropertyAttribute.PropertyName;
            return jsonProperty;
        }
        else
        {
            return jsonProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is now for querying the database. When I make a LINQ query like this

```
var _DbClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri("_DB URI_"), "_DB KEY_", new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CosmosDbDefaultContractResolver()
}, connectionPolicy);

var Query = _DbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>().Where(a => a.DocumentType == 0).AsEnumerable();
```

the query statement is wrong because is referred to the original property name `DocumentType` instead of `DT` specified in the CosmosDbProperty attribute so the query fails.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach the problem differently. Instead of trying to make the model behave differently, I would implement a repository pattern that exposes APIs with the class you want, but maps the properties to the internal DB model class.

i.e. I'd have the class below that's returned or consumed by the repository.

```
public class CosmosDbDocumentBase
{

    public virtual string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual int DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
}
```

But I'd also have an internal DB model:

```
class CosmosDbModel
{
    public virtual string CID { get; set; }
    public virtual int DT { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string PK { get; set; }
}
```

You can use automapper to bi-directionally map the fields (or just map them manually) and the mapping logic can be shared across all repository methods. This would avoid all the unnecessarily complicated annotations and considering you *do* want a JSON representation and a separate DB representation, 2 separate classes would provide the necessary separation of concerns.